# What does Residue multiplication mean?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $ a, b, c, n \in \mathbb{Z}, \qquad$ where $n>0, \qquad$ then $a\cdot b \texttt{ mod } n = c$ is called modular multiplication.

The article that I am reading mentions Modular and Residue multiplication differently. So what does residue multiplication mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, modular multiplication means that we multiply residue classes, i.e.,
$[a]\cdot [b]=[ab]$, where $[a]$ is a residue class in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. See also [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730248/multiplication-of-residue-classes-modulo-n). So it is the same operation, just emphasising different aspects (modular resp. residue class).